# MacBook Pro not recognising 1 (it's own) SSD

Tags: boot, mac, ssd

This MacBook Pro was upgraded with an SSD, few months after came back with the "Question Mark" Folder, done checks, replaced SATA cable. All good.

Now back again with the "same problem". Done checks.

- SSD will not show (in Disk Utility) either from SATA or USB
- SSD will show and boot on or other machines.
- MacBook pro reads other Drives, USB, and even SSDs.

So conclusion, it's just this SSD that it doesn't want to read.

Now in the ideal world, I would understand why this is happening before swapping a 500Gb SSD without knowing the reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: What other machines did you try this on? i assume another mac or was it a windows machine?

Comment: USB Caddy into Mac Mini, The SSD shows up and now it's doing a full disk copy with CCC. Even booted it up with it.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed another SATA cable and solved the issue.
Which I was hoping was something else.

Now I'm just worried that we'll have to replace this cable every month or so!